# React Router Dom v5 nested routes don't work

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

Been trying to figure out why the nested routes don't work in my child component. What am I missing here? Below is the component that fails to display anything when trying both routes "/" and "/add-new-strategy".

Here is my  component.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Nav } from '../../Nav'
import { Home } from '../Home'
import { Admin } from '../Admin'
import './index.scss'

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <main className="main-container">
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/admin">
            <Admin />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

And this is the child component that is not displaying anything even though I have the  and  done.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'
import { AdminSideBar } from '../../AdminSideBar'
import { AddNewStrategy } from '../AddNewStrategy'

export const Admin = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <AdminSideBar />
        <div className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/add-new-strategy">
              <AddNewStrategy />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" exact>
              Dashboard should show up here...
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/add-new-strategy" component={AddNewStrategy} />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I tried that just now and it didn't work. Nothing is in the dom inside the `<div className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4"></div>`

Comment: Sorry that did not work either. But I found a solution and posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using `useRouteMatch` to specify the full path worked.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  useRouteMatch
} from 'react-router-dom'
import { AdminSideBar } from '../../AdminSideBar'
import { AddNewStrategy } from '../AddNewStrategy'

export const Admin = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch()

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <AdminSideBar />
        <div className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
          <Switch>
            <Route path={`${path}/add-new-strategy`}>
              <AddNewStrategy />
            </Route>
            <Route path={path} exact>
              Dashboard should show up here...
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where did you placed the `useRouteMatch ` ?  I have same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68451408/protected-routes-for-react-router-v5-isnt-working

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 more methods to route from a component to next,

```
      <Route path="/add-new-strategy" component={AddNewStrategy} />
      
                              or
      <Route path="/" exact render={()=>{<AddNewStrategy/>}} />
```

for nested routing define full url and give exact 'true'

```
 <Route path="/firstcomponent/secondcomponent" exact component={AddNewStrategy} />
```

please try these